# How to filter an array that has mixed data types

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array which is like this:

```
const AllFiles = [

    {name: "ExistingFile1", mimetype: "image/jpg", size: "500"},

    [ 
     File, // This is the New File itself (see File API)
     {name: "NewFile1", mimetype: "video/mp4", size: "9000"}
    ],

    {name: "ExistingFile2", mimetype: "video/mp4", size: "4000"},

    [ 
     File, // This is the New File itself (see File API)
     {name: "NewFile2", mimetype: "image/jpg", size: "500"}
    ],

 ]
```

As you can see the `AllFiles` array contains a mix of objects and arrays.

I need to filter the `AllFiles` array to only return items where the `mimetype` starts with `"image/"`.

So I started off with the following:

```
const FilteredFiles = AllFiles.filter((FileItem, index) => FileItem.mimetype.startsWith("image/"))
```

The problem is that it only looks for the `mimetype` where it is in a top level object. Its does not look deeper where a New File has `mimetype` in the second level object within an array.

To get the `mimetype` of existing files you need to use: `FileItem[0].mimetype`

But to get the `mimetype` for new files you need to use: `FileItem[0][1].mimetype`

Because of this mismatch I am unable to filter the `AllFiles` array. How could this possibly be achieved?

Comment: What about using an if statement? You can then create a logical branch depending on wether the property exists or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `??` operator to have a very compact solution:

```js
const AllFiles = [{name:"ExistingFile1",mimetype:"image/jpg",size:"500"},["FILE",{name:"NewFile1",mimetype:"video/mp4",size:"9000"}],{name:"ExistingFile2",mimetype:"video/mp4",size:"4000"},["FILE",{name:"NewFile2",mimetype:"image/jpg",size:"500"}]];
 
const result = AllFiles.filter(f => (f[1] ?? f).mimetype.startsWith('image'));

result.forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

Comment: this is very elegant and works thank you

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to check if the entity in the iteration has the `mimetype` property. If it does, then you can read it directly. If it does not then you can assume its an array and you need to instead read from the second entity in the array.

```js
const File = "foo", AllFiles = [{name:"ExistingFile1",mimetype:"image/jpg",size:"500"},["foo",{name:"NewFile1",mimetype:"video/mp4",size:"9000"}],{name:"ExistingFile2",mimetype:"video/mp4",size:"4000"},["foo",{name:"NewFile2",mimetype:"image/jpg",size:"500"}]];

const filteredFiles = AllFiles.filter(entity => {
  const obj = entity.hasOwnProperty('mimetype') ? entity : entity[1];
  return obj.mimetype.startsWith("image/");
});

console.log(filteredFiles);
```

Note that this is only for demonstration purposes. In a production system I'd suggest a few more checks to make this more robust, such as checking the data types are as expected, but the above example is the simplistic version of the pattern to follow.

Comment: this is nice thank you